# client can't talk HTTPS to WireMock: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

Tags: java, ssl, https, wiremock

I have the following mock configuration:

```
 public MockedServer() {
        super(new WireMockConfiguration()
                .httpsPort(8443)
                .keystorePath("identity.jks")
                .keystorePassword("password")
        );

        System.out.println(this.getOptions().httpsSettings());
    }
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mobmad/433ba54e9cb97d6d7771) to generate the keystore

And I'm running the tested JAR as follows:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar", pathToJar,
            "--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=" + keystore).start();
```

The problem is that the client throws the following exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

Why?

It's also worth mentioning that there shouldn't be an SSL certificate issue from the client as it is (insecurely)  configured to trust all certs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem finally. I'll leave it for future readers:

When accessing the port you should use `httpsPort()` and not `port()`.

Comment: But the code in your question already uses `httpsPort`...

Comment: Yeah but on another module that reads the port I used mistakenly `port()`

Comment: Then may be you should post the other code in your question, because question and code currently do not match.